# Python Selenium close и quit всегда вылазит окно Прекращена работа программы

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Всегда когда использую метод close или quit то вылазит окно прекращена работа программы Firefox. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

использую винду 10

Comment: нет, не выдает.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему, она почему-то оказалась в том что я юзал прокси, почему так, великая загадка